# CORS with Express App on AWS Fargate behind ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, cors, amazon-elb, aws-fargate

So I have an Express server running on an AWS Fargate instance, behind an ALB. The Express App is setup in a fairly standard way:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: ['*'],
    credentials: false,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST']
}));
```

All the endpoints work when using Postman, but when calling it from my React app that's deployed via AWS Amplify, I'm getting a CORS error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/upload' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Everything I've read says that ALB doesn't support CORS and just passes the request through to the server, and that CORS needs to be implemented on the server; however, CORS is very clearly being applied to the Express server. What am I missing in implementing CORS here?

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. Did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: Just adding some details, it seems that ECS doesn't receive the `req.origin` value properly . when I log `req.get('orign')` it turns out to be undefined. Still looking for a solution

Comment: If you open the web debugger in your React app (ctrl+shift+c on Firefox and Chrome) and go to the network requests, do you actually see the correct CORS headers in the request/response tabs?